# Weird issue in cms base application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, content-management-system

Suddenly a page in my asp.net mvc 2 cms starts crashing and give output like this
[image]

I dont have any clue why its stop working. Does any body knows?

My application is on asp.net mvc-2, c#, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [gzip encoding](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) caveat.